# On and Off switch redirect to another page

Tags: jquery, html, css

Just new here in stackoverflow and jquery. I would like to ask if this is possible? I have this following codes

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" style="width: 105px; overflow-y: visible; margin-top: 9px;">
   <select name="slider" id="flip-b" data-role="slider">
    <option class="no" value="Off">Off</option>
    <option class="yes" value="On" selected="selected">On</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

What I would like to happen is when I select the `<option class="yes" value="on">` it will redirect to another page. Is it possible in jquery? and how will I make it?

All comments and suggestion is greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('#flip-b').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "On") {
        window.location = "url";
    }
});
```

DEMO:http://jsfiddle.net/AmitJoki/U63Mp/